# How to auto add slashes to specific uri before proxy redirection?

Tags: ubuntu, mod-rewrite, proxy, apache2

I am facing a problem:
I am using an **ubuntu server** with **apache2** acting as a **proxy** for my domain name. this redirects to different servers and folders depending on what is called...

this is my proxy config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

...
    ProxyPass /document/ http://**.**.**.**/
    ProxyPassReverse /document/ http://**.**.**.**/
...
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName *********************

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /****/****/****/*****************************
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /****/****/*****/***********************
    SSLCipherSuite *****************************************

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On

    SSLCertificateChainFile /****/****/****/********************************
...
    ProxyPass /document/ http://**.**.**.**/
    ProxyPassReverse /document/ http://**.**.**.**/
...
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</VirtualHost>
```

My concern is that all **http(s)://mon-domaine.ext/document/** requests are functional but not **http(s)://mon-domaine.ext/document**

So I tryed to add this in the config:

```
    ProxyPass /document http://**.**.**.**/
    ProxyPassReverse /document http://**.**.**.**/
```

the request **http(s)://mon-domaine.ext/document** is indeed redirected by the proxy but only part of the page is loaded, the content of the image or css folders is not loaded ..

so i tried using **modrewrite** to add the slash automatically..
So I tried one by one different config by adding just after the **rewriteEngine on**:

```
->  RewriteRule ^(document)$ $1/ [L,PT]
->  RewriteRule ^/document /document/ [R=301]
-> and other I don't remember...
```

I also tried to play with "**DirectorySlash On**" and "**Off**" without results

I will add that after every changes in config I **restarted apache2** and used a **private page**, **empty cache** etc...

in short, none of these attempts have succeeded and I am beginning to despair, a helping hand would be greatly appreciated.

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Is `/document` a physical directory? At both the source and target? Or just one or the other?

Comment: @MrWhite : /document is just the name I add in the uri to target the directory /var/www/html in an other server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution, so to get around i made a subdomain...